# Convert an Integer inside a Bash loop into a Variable

Tags: bash, sh

I have a Bash script:

```
How would I loop through a list of numbered variables and then make the variable into a loop.

Example:

//Variables
DIR="/home/"
LIMIT=8
1="cupcake/"
2="cake/"
3="icecream/"
4="donut/"
5="cocoa/"
6="whipcream/"
7="cookie/"
8="coffee/"

for i in {1..8} // The number of variables
do
  cd "$DIR${i}"; // cd /home/cupcake/
  make something;
done
```

Comment: N. B. Comments in shell-scripts starts with `#`, not with `//`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways will be reasonable.

Using positional parameters:

```
set "cupcake" "cake" "icecream" "donut" "cocoa" "whipcream" "cookie" "coffee"

for i; do
    cd "${DIR}/${i}" || continue
    # do something
done
```

It’s not in custom to store final slash of path in variables, so I use `"${DIR}/${i}"`. Anyway, `cd` won’t fail at `/home//cupcake`.

Or using array:

```
A=( "cupcake" "cake" "icecream" "donut" "cocoa" "whipcream" "cookie" "coffee" )

for i in "${A[@]}"; do
    cd "${DIR}/${i}" || continue
    # do something
done
```

Please note, you should use `"${A[@]}"` to handle spaces properly, not `${A[*]}`. `|| continue` interrupts current iteration if `cd` fails.

Array obviously is more flexible: you can explicitly set a position as you tried to do in your question

```
A=(
    [1]="cupcake"
    [7]="cookie"
    [2]="cake"  
    [3]="icecream"
    [4]="donut"
    [6]="whipcream"
    [5]="cocoa"
    [8]="coffee"
)
```

edit any single element later

```
A[4]="doughnut"
```

delete any element

```
unset A[4]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'll pretend that your numbered variables are parameters. That's what numbered variables are for.

```
for i in {1..8} // The number of variables
do
  eval cd "$DIR\${$i}"; // cd /home/cupcake/
  make something;
done
```

However, if this is indeed parameters, you can safely use `$1` and keep shifting until you've referenced them all.

```
for i in {1..8} // The number of variables
do
  cd "$DIR$1"; // cd /home/cupcake/
  make something;
  shift
done
```

Instead of using `for {1..8}` you can check for the number of parameters passed `$#`.

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] // The number of variables
do
  cd "$DIR$1"; // cd /home/cupcake/
  make something;
  shift
done
```

Comment: There is more safer and clear way than `eval` to reference variable indirect: `${!i}`. `cd "${DIR}${!i}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Numbered variables are reserved for script/function arguments. Rename them.

Comment: You are right that they are reserved. But you can set and reset them at will. Try `set one two three four` then check the values of `$1` to `$4`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want [an array](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) which also allows a for loop, although it would look more like

```
for subdir in ${dirarray[*]}
do
    cd "$DIR$subdir";
    make something;
done
```

Comment: `for subdir in ${dirarray[*]}` it fails to handle spaces. Use `"${dirarray[@]}"`.